Removing BIRT viewer from the BIRT project to deploy on Wildfly 27
We are using BIRT on our project which currently has dependencies on Javax.
We need to deploy on Wildfly 27 and migrate to Jakarta but BIRT viewer has a dependency on AXIS2 which is not yet migrated to Jakarta.
We have agreed on removing the BIRT viewer module to bypass this issue.
However, the team is having little success in achieving that due to unfamiliarity with the technologies used.
Could we get clear steps on how to remove the viewer module and have it compile successfully?
Intellij IDE is being used instead of Eclipse.
Tried removing the entire module but compilation is failing. Errors are hard to diagnose because
intellij code highlighting isn't working due to BIRT being developed in Eclipse.

Method without BIRT Viewer:
WAR - WEB-INF
WEB-INF
├── lib
├── reports
│   ├── Students2.rptdesign  <-- report1
│   ├── hello_world.rptdesign <-- report2 (copy from birt.war)
│   └── hello_world_chart.rptdesign <-- report3  (copy from birt.war)
└── web.xml

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>helloweb6</display-name>

<!-- report1 -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Report1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>reportFile</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/reports/Students2.rptdesign</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Report1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/report1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<!-- report2 -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Report2Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>reportFile</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/reports/hello_world.rptdesign</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>paramString</param-name>
      <param-value>my+parameter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>paramInteger</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>paramList</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Report2Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/report2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<!-- report3 -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Report3Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>reportFile</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/reports/hello_world_chart.rptdesign</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>paramCust</param-name>
      <param-value>130</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Report3Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/report3</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

ReportServlet.java
package com.example;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private IReportEngine birtEngine;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
        try {
            Platform.startup(config);
        } catch (BirtException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String reportTypeDefult = "html";
        String reportType = request.getParameter("reportType");
        //html , pdf
        if (reportType == null || reportType.isEmpty()) {
            reportType = reportTypeDefult;
        }

        String reportFile = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("reportFile");
        try {
            IReportRunnable design = birtEngine.openReportDesign(getServletContext().getRealPath(reportFile));
            IRunAndRenderTask task = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);

            if (getServletName().equals("Report2Servlet")) {
                // Get default parameters from web.xml
                String paramString = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("paramString");
                // If parameters are passed in the URL query, the default values ​​are overwritten.
                String paramStringFromRequest = request.getParameter("paramString");
                if (paramStringFromRequest != null && !paramStringFromRequest.isEmpty()) {
                    paramString = paramStringFromRequest;
                }

                if (paramString == null || paramString.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ServletException("Required parameter 'paramString' is not set.");
                }
                task.setParameterValue("paramString", paramString);

                // Get default parameters from web.xml
                String paramInteger = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("paramInteger");
                // If parameters are passed in the URL query, the default values ​​are overwritten.
                String paramIntegerFromRequest = request.getParameter("paramInteger");
                if (paramIntegerFromRequest != null && !paramIntegerFromRequest.isEmpty()) {
                    paramInteger = paramIntegerFromRequest;
                }

                if (paramInteger == null || paramInteger.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ServletException("Required parameter 'paramInteger' is not set.");
                }


                // Only For Report 2 - Setting Report Parameters
                Integer paramIntegerValue = Integer.valueOf(paramInteger);
                task.setParameterValue("paramInteger", paramIntegerValue);

                // Get default parameters from web.xml
                String paramList = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("paramList");
                // If parameters are passed in the URL query, the default values ​​are overwritten.
                String paramListFromRequest = request.getParameter("paramList");
                if (paramListFromRequest != null && !paramListFromRequest.isEmpty()) {
                    paramList = paramListFromRequest;
                }

                if (paramList == null || paramList.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ServletException("Required parameter 'paramList' is not set.");
                }


                // Only For Report 2 - Setting Report Parameters
                System.out.println("paramList = " + paramList);
                Integer paramListValue = Integer.valueOf(paramList);
                System.out.println("paramListValue  = " + paramListValue);
                task.setParameterValue("paramList", paramListValue);
            }


            if (getServletName().equals("Report3Servlet")) {
                // Get default parameters from web.xml
                String paramCust = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("paramCust");
                // If parameters are passed in the URL query, the default values ​​are overwritten.
                String paramCustFromRequest = request.getParameter("paramCust");
                if (paramCustFromRequest != null && !paramCustFromRequest.isEmpty()) {
                    paramCust = paramCustFromRequest;
                }

                if (paramCust == null || paramCust.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ServletException("Required parameter 'paramCust' is not set.");
                }

                // Only For Report 3 - Setting Report Parameters
                BigDecimal paramCustValue = new BigDecimal(paramCust);

                task.setParameterValue("paramCust", paramCustValue);
            }

            if (reportType.equals("html")) {
                HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
                options.setOutputFormat(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML);
                options.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                task.setRenderOption(options);
            }
            if (reportType.equals("pdf")) {
                // Configuring PDF output options
                PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
                options.setOutputFormat(PDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.pdf");

                // Set the PDF output stream as the response output stream
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                options.setOutputStream(out);
                task.setRenderOption(options);
            }
            task.run();
            task.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException("Error generating report", e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        birtEngine.destroy();
        Platform.shutdown();
        super.destroy();
    }
}

put it into apache-tomcat-10.1.31/webapps/hello
Test 1 - Query MySQL Database - html view
http://localhost:8080/hello/report1

Test 2 - Query MySQL Database - pdf view
http://localhost:8080/hello/report1?reportType=pdf

Test 3 - Report with Image and Chart - html view
http://localhost:8080/hello/report3

Note: Use html view to display, but the pictures and charts of the report are not displayed normally.
Test 4 - Report with Image and Chart - pdf view
http://localhost:8080/hello/report3?reportType=pdf

Note: Use pdf view to display, the pictures and charts of the report are displayed normally.

Java Code: To display a BIRT report without using BIRT Viewer, all you need is to develop a ReportServlet and use IReportEngine birtEngine.

Config File : In addition, set the url and start parameters of the ReportServlet corresponding report in web.xml.

Report File: BIRT report files are placed under the WEB-INF/reports directory in the WAR.



Quick Irregular Answer:

Good news, you can still use BIRT Viewer.
Bad news, you have to use a special jar.

BIRT viewer dependency on javax package. (core: viewservlets.jar)
Basic Test
Download BIRT Runtime
https://download.eclipse.org/birt/updates/release/latest/

download birt-runtime-4.17.0-202409160710.zip (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/updates/release/4.17.0/downloads/birt-runtime-4.17.0-202409160710.zip)

Unzip Birt Runtime ZIP
unzip birt-runtime-4.17.0-202409160710.zip
Test on Tomcat 9 (javax)

JDK 17

apache-tomcat-9.0.96

Found birt.war in birt-runtime-4.17.0-202409160710 directory

put birt.war into apache-tomcat-9.0.96/webapps

startup Tomcat 9


cd apache-tomcat-9.0.96/bin
./startup.sh

Open Birt URL
http://localhost:8080/birt
000.png

Report 1
001.png

Report 2
002.png


shutdown Tomcat 9

cd apache-tomcat-9.0.96/bin
./shutdown.sh

Migrate to Tomcat 10.1 (jakarta)

JDK 17

apache-tomcat-10.1.31

create directoty webapps-javaee under apache-tomcat-10.1.31

put birt.war into apache-tomcat-10.1.31/webapps-javaee

startup Tomcat 10


cd apache-tomcat-10.1.31/bin
./startup.sh

Open Birt URL
http://localhost:8080/birt

Report 1
same as Tomcat 9
Report 2
same as Tomcat 9

shutdown Tomcat 10

cd apache-tomcat-10.1.31/bin
./shutdown.sh


The contents of many jar files in apache-tomcat-10.1.31/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib have been modified.
one of the example: viewservlets.jar

viewservlets.jar

org/eclipse/birt/report/servlet/ViewerServlet.class



import package name is jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig,
package org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.context.IContext;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.IFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtReportServiceFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.IViewerReportService;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.utility.BirtUtility;

public class ViewerServlet
extends BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet {
...



viewservlets.jar

org/eclipse/birt/report/servlet/ViewerServlet.class



Here is the original, unmodified Birt Viewer Server code:
import package name is javax.servlet.ServletConfig,
package org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.context.IContext;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.IFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtReportServiceFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.IViewerReportService;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.utility.BirtUtility;

public class ViewerServlet
extends BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet {
...

Now you have the relevant jars for BIRT Viewer that supports jakarta
Good news, you can still use BIRT Viewer.
Now you have the relevant jars for BIRT Viewer that supports jakarta
Bad news, you have to use a special jar
You must use the modified jar files. They are in the apache-tomcat-10.1.31/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib directory. Your project must copy these modified jar files. There are 105 files in them. Modified (the result after comparing with the jar file under apache-tomcat-9.0.96/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib).
If you still decide not to use Birt Viewer in the end, it's okay. The answer is simple. It's perfectly fine to just provide a BIRT Report in PDF format, but a BIRT Report in HTML format may still cause errors in some formats. (But this is Another answer.)
